# Post on facebook Friends profile without opening dialog box?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               friend, @"to",
                               @"100xxxx",@"from",
                               @"I'm also using thex xx for iOS app", @"message",

                               nil];
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[[delegate m_Facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"/xxx6842/feed"   // or use page ID instead of 'me'
               andParams:params
           andHttpMethod:@"POST"
             andDelegate:self];
```

I am trying this a lot but got error message !!

while i am using hackbook api !!

thanks for every one !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `params` variable in your code is a dictionary with a 'message' key and value, you should also need to make sure to ask the user for the publish_stream extended permission.

Comment: hey i am getting your point . can elaborate a bit more please where i am have to use currently i am using :-- if (![appDelegate.m_Facebook isSessionValid]) {       //Show loging dialog
      [appDelegate.m_Facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"user_photos",@"user_videos",@"offline_access",@"user_checkins",@"friends_checkins",nil] delegate:self];
    }

Comment: looks like you are using an older version of the SDK. Also the offline_access permission is deprecated. See the sample over here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/